# Babelify and native Node modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Is there a way to [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) native Node modules (e.g. `crypto`, `fs`, `path`) when using [Babelify](https://babeljs.io/) with [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)?

For example:

```
'use strict';

import $ from 'jquery';
import fs from 'fs'; // <------ this line causes an error

var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('foo.json', 'utf8'));

$(document).ready(function () {
  // stuff
});
```

Browserify gives me this error when I try to run it:

> Error: tried to statically call `{ readFile: [Function: readFile], readFileSync: [Function: readFileSync], readdir: [Function: readdir], readdirSync: [Function: readdirSync] }` as a function while parsing file: /home/vincent/www/project1/resources/js/foo.js while parsing file: /home/vincent/www/project1/resources/js/foo.js

I've also tried the following with the same results:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { fs } from fs;
```

Comment: I think that primarily depends on how the module is exporting the values.

Comment: @FelixKling Ok but neither jquery nor fs export any modules so why does Babelify only pick up jquery?

Comment: Uh? Of course `fs` exports something, it is a module after all. Looking at its [source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js), it does something similar to `exports.foo = 42;`, so `import * as fs from 'fs';` should work IMO. This may help: http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/babel-commonjs.html

Comment: @FelixKling Oh I thought you meant export as in the ES6 export. Anyways I found out that it doesn't work due to breaking static analysis: https://github.com/babel/babelify/issues/81

Comment: Ah right. Importing is not the issue, but usage with browersify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [a known issue](https://github.com/babel/babelify/issues/81) with [brfs](https://github.com/substack/brfs) and Babelify:

> It will eventually be possible once static-module can handle ES6 imports. For now you need to 'require' brfs with CommonJS syntax, and run the brfs transform after babelify.

Sources:

- https://github.com/babel/babelify/issues/81
- https://github.com/substack/brfs/issues/39